# Sequelize Associations :Unhandled rejection TypeError: order.addItems is not a function

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

Association is defined as :

```
Orders.belongsToMany(Items, { through: OrderItem });
Items.belongsToMany(Orders, { through: OrderItem });
```

I'm trying

```
 Orders.create(orderDetails).then(order => {
            orderDetails.items.forEach(item => {
                Items.findByPk(item.code).then(item => {
                    order.addItem(item)
                })
            });    
        })
```

Why this giving me the error that

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: order.addItem is not a function
```

Comment: Because `addItem` is not a member of `order` object. log order to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I am using `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`. Besides, there is another issue with your code. You create an order, but sequelize will not create the `items` in the `orderDetails` object. You need to create them with associations. You should create items using `Orders.create(orderDetails, { include: [Items] })`. You can check this [docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#hasmany---belongstomany-association) for details.

Let's go back to your question, `order.addItem` should work. Here is the completed working example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { Model, BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';

class Orders extends Model {
  public id!: number;
  public addItem!: BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin<Items, number>;
}
Orders.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'order' });

class Items extends Model {
  public code!: number;
  public name!: string;
}
Items.init(
  {
    code: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'item' },
);

class OrderItem extends Model {
  public orderId!: number;
  public itemCode!: number;
}
OrderItem.init({}, { sequelize, modelName: 'orderItem' });

Orders.belongsToMany(Items, { through: OrderItem });
Items.belongsToMany(Orders, { through: OrderItem });

export { sequelize, Orders, Items, OrderItem };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize, Orders, Items } from './';

describe('59818484', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    await sequelize.close();
  });
  it('should pass', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(3);
    const orderDetails = {
      items: [
        { code: 1, name: 'a' },
        { code: 2, name: 'b' },
      ],
    };
    let count = 0;
    Orders.create(orderDetails).then(async (order: Orders) => {
      const items = await Items.findAll();
      expect(items).toHaveLength(0);
      orderDetails.items.forEach((item) => {
        Items.findByPk(item.code)
          .then((item: Items) => {
            expect(typeof order.addItem).toBe('function');
            return order.addItem(item);
          })
          .finally(() => {
            count++;
            if (count === orderDetails.items.length) {
              done();
            }
          });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Integration test results:

```sh
 PASS  src/examples/stackoverflow/59818484/index.test.ts
  59818484
    ✓ should pass (34ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.23s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/59818484